# Problems with sun lighting in eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm creating a small solar system where i would like to show the dark and the bright side of the the earth. My problem is that when i see the earth from behind, to show the dark side, there appears a light around the edges (first picture, only in eevee). But i would like to see it just all dark. If i put down specular in the light settings to 0, i get the desired result (second picture) but then i miss the reflection on the earth.

I tried it with a spot, sun and a point lamp. with the point lamp it works, but it does not work for the whole project. The problem appears with a sun and also a spot lamp.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

---

Thanks for the detailed information.
Unfortunately it didnt solve the problem. I opened a complete new blend file with a new uv sphere, no materials added at all. and there i got the same effect, but only if the light is in a certain distance from the uv sphere.

[image]

Comment: Uhm do you have a background image/color, like HDRI ? Also what size is your earth. If it's larger than your light source's radius, I imagine this might happen too. What results do you get from cycles rendering?

Comment: i have no background image or color. As the background should be just black and there is only 1 exact light source, i thought it may disturb the restult. but i will try a HDRI.
I played with the radius, and also made it smaller, but if it is too small, the light source reflects as a light pulb on the surface. 
Cycles rendering works perfectly, but my computer is to slow to render an animation with cycles.

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried removing all the materials to see if the shadows work normally? If yes, then I think you need to check your earth' materials. If not, are you able to share your blendfile?

Comment: please share your blend file

Comment: yes i tried to remove all the materials. 

Here is the blendfile:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Qkem38Br" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Qkem38Br/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new  blend file to see if I could recreate your issue. I created a light, and sphere with no materials and I got it:

[image]

To fix this you need to select your light source and enable "Contact Shadows"

[image]

It took a little time to figure this out, lol.

Comment: That's it! Wow thanks a lot for your time and effort, thats really great and will save me a headache :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Your Bump map strenght was too strong. Here I have some images:

I placed some random noise textures in the bump node and saw that the light of the sun reaches the backof it. This is because the Bump value is way too high. The same goes for the moon, except your moon uses a displacement value.

It's very easy to oversee this issue.

[image: Image 1.]

I you adjust it to a lower value, you will get your desired result as seen here:

[image]

Notice how the shadows look normal now? I usually keep the Bump strenght to 1 and lower the distance value a lot. Try playing with these settings to what suits you.

Hope this helps!